# How to add a custom button in rte plugin in aem/cq

Tags: aem, rte

How to add a custom button in rte plugin/cq?

The below path is for hyperlink

```
/apps/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/form/rte/plugins/LinkDialog.js
```

I need to add a custom button in rte plugin to extend the hyperlink functionality?

Comment: Please edit your question cause it's not clear what do you need: you need custom button for your custom widget or you need just custom icon for default widget (Link Plugin) which was overwritten?

Answer (score 3):

To provide a new button/plugin in RTE, a new clientlib will have to be created. In the js file, the intended functionality of button can be implemented in ExtJs. In CSS file, the appearance/image of thee button can be specified.

Then the newly created clientlib can be registered as a plugin for RTE by using following line :

CUI.rte.plugins.PluginRegistry.register("pluginName",ClientlibName.PluginName.Plugin);

The entire process has been described step by step in this excellent [article](http://experience-aem.blogspot.com/2014/02/aem-cq-56-extend-richtext-editor-add-new-plugin-pullquote.html).